# Strange line appearing at Textview in Sony Ericsson Xperia Ray st18i

Tags: android, textview, sony-xperia

We implemented a listView that includes a textview that we set to be clickable (in the adapter we added the method). We set the style to change when clicked (list_selector_background).

This is working pretty well in several devices we use for testing, depending on the android version the color turns grey or orange. However only and only in Sony Ericsson Xperia Ray st18i we are finding an strange behavior, the status on click includes an small line in the middle, that only appears in this device. Is not appearing in devices with the same android version (2.3.4).

I attach here a photo of the problem we face (look at the line that goes through the text fhh:

[image]

We have performed and captured the following evidences:

- Is not happening with other devices on version 2.3
- Is not happening with other apps in the same mobile.
- Is only happening in this deveices between 20 different ones.
- Looking in internet we have not find any evidence that this is a normal behavior.
- Changing the list_selector is not fixing the things.

After performing several investigations we run out of ideas. Can somebody give a suggestion of how to remove the line from the TextView?

I attach the textview code.

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/userlist_item_name"
            style="android:textViewStyle"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/EditList"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageShare"
            android:background="@drawable/list_color"
            android:drawable="@android:drawable/list_selector_background"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:paddingBottom="9dp"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingTop="9dp"
            android:state_pressed="true"
            android:text="ItemName"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textStyle="normal" />
```